# How to use spring constraint on a moving object?

Tags: rigging, constraints, rigid-body-simulation

I’m trying to animate a bike that will be going over rough terrain, and I want the rider’s body to react with physics. I’m trying to use the “generic spring” rigid body constraint, but whenever I use it, the object hanging from the spring only moves in one spot. If I want an object to react to the motion of the bike (jiggling up and down as it goes over bumps and hills) I need it to be a movable system, and to be able to react to that motion. Is there another way to accomplish this, or am I not using the constraints right?

Comment: Related?: [how-to-build-a-carriage-that-reacts-to-an-uneven-ground](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135285/how-to-build-a-carriage-that-reacts-to-an-uneven-ground/136090#136090)