# How to make that wheel follows road bumps

Tags: animation, constraints

I'm working some simple project where I have a car which driving on road. Road has bumps. Of course, as rookie amateur :) , my wheels sinking into bumps. I tried various methods I found over internet, but had no success with any (rigid body, track to constarint, stretch to constarint, shrinkwrap constraint, etc. probably I don't know to use properly any of those).

I attaching simple example .blend with one non flat plane as ground and one cylinder as wheel, animated to roiling from one end of plane to another. Is there some simple basic method, where I can tell cylinder to follow bumps on ground when rolling? I would like to avoid some complex methods as rigging, etc. cause I'm beginner and I believe that solution could be simple.

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: are you talking about one wheel or several wheels? it's a bit more difficult to make a whole chassis

Comment: I am talking about standard car with 4 wheels.

Comment: So maybe you should specify in the title that what you're looking for is car rigging. And I'm not sure you can do it without an armature.

Comment: I answered here for a simple rig but it doesn't allow to simulate a real chassis: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135285/how-to-build-a-carriage-that-reacts-to-an-uneven-ground

Comment: I could accept your link as answer because this is the answer on question I asked. I just tried it and it is working like a charm for wheels. But you are right - this is more complex and copy location constarint will not work well, cause wheels will pass through car body on bumps. I will take little more time and start rigging, I saw rigacar free add on, it seems that performing well and is not too much complicate for me. Thanks anyway

Comment: great then  ;)  yes there's a way to properly rig a car, I haven't found a good tutorial yet

Comment: This one is very good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3XQxA_-TzY&t=25 He is also Rigacar add on creator, add on is hosted here: https://github.com/digicreatures/rigacar He explaining slowly and in details (in tutorial) so beginner like me can fully understand - my car is driving like blaze now :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to build a carriage that reacts to an uneven ground](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135285/how-to-build-a-carriage-that-reacts-to-an-uneven-ground)