# move a mechanism according to the terrain

Tags: animation

I'm having such a bad time on animating the rows of a planting machine. The rows must follow the deformation of the terrain, but animating them one by one and trying to syncronize as they pass through the deformation is proving to be a real pain in the @$$! So I was wondering if there's a simple way to make those rows to move according to the terrain's deformation. Anyone knows how?
**Note:** the disc and the shank must be part under the ground.
[image: rows]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: to add to Crantisz' answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135285/how-to-build-a-carriage-that-reacts-to-an-uneven-ground

Answer (score 7):

If you don't have big valleys and sharp surfaces, you can use Shrinkwrap constraint for that:

[image]

[image]

If you set **Distance** positive, the object center will be above the ground, negative - below.

Comment: Thank you so much friend! I'll try doing that and parent the movemet to the rest of the mechanism!