# How to place object on surface physically correct? (Floating Boat)

Tags: animation, physics

Good day. I have a scene where I want to place boat on the water and animate it (boat is floating on the waves).
[image: boat on the water]
Can I achive it in easy way using something like physical placement on surfaces or I should change location of boat manually in each frame?

P.S. water is a cube with wave modifier.
[image: water modifier]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a boat that moves on X or Y, use a subdivided plane under the boat, give it a *Shrinkwrap* modifier, give the boat a *Copy Location* constraint with the plane as *Target*, and move the plane. See my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135285/how-to-build-a-carriage-that-reacts-to-an-uneven-ground).

If the boat is supposed to stay still (like it seems to be the case here) you can simply parent it to 3 vertices of you water surface: Select the boat in *Object* mode, shift select the water, switch to *Edit* mode, select 3 vertices, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Make Vertex Parent*:

[image]

Comment: So simple, and surprisingly convincing!

Comment: I had the idea from a video that I've seen recently but I can't remember where, that said it only works if the boat is still, otherwise I would use a plane underneath that would have a Shrinkwrap modifier, and the boat a Copy Location with the plane as Target

Comment: @moonboots wow, you cool! It's the thing that I need. But I can't understand what you mean in "...Copy Location with the plane as Target"?

Comment: @Сергей The method I explain in the comment is only if the boat is supposed to move, do you want me to explain? if it stays still, use the method I explain in my answer.

Comment: @moonboots I want to make my boat floating on waves AND moving, so please, explain about second method. Oh, I see you edited your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: i don't see a boat here. I just see a rotten box...

Comment: ok but you saw a sea when it was just a bunch of polygons, ah ah i got you Jesus

Comment: by the way I've heard you were able to WALK on the sea, do you use a Shrinkwrap modifer or what???

Comment: of course i am using geonodes -> proximity node 

Comment: oh ok, and for the multiplication of loaves, is it a kind of particle system?

Comment: of course it is geometry nodes -> distribute points/loaf on faces. So every face / human gets one loaf